# How do I reverse a sublist in a list in place?

Tags: python, list, function, sublist

I'm supposed to create a function, which input is a list and two numbers, the function reverses the sublist which its place is indicated by the two numbers.
for example this is what it's supposed to do:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
>>> reverse_sublist (lst,0,4) 
>>> lst  [4, 3, 2, 1, 5]
```

I created a function and it works, but I'm not sure is it's in place.
This is my code:

```
def reverse_sublist(lst,start,end):
    sublist=lst[start:end]
    sublist.reverse()
    lst[start:end]=sublist
    print(lst)
```

Comment: You can check whether it's in-place by using `id()`.

Comment: No, this is not actually inplace as we have to create a temporary list (`sublist`)

Comment: "In place" is ambiguous. It might mean, "mutate the input object". It might mean, "use `O(1)` additional memory". The latter is usually called an "in-place algorithm", whereas the former is usually called "reverse the list in place", so the exact wording of your assignment might provide clues.

Answer (score 30):

```
def reverse_sublist(lst,start,end):
    lst[start:end] = lst[start:end][::-1]
    return lst
```

Comment: Surely even the most avid fan of slice notation can deign to use `reversed` in this case? ;-)

Comment: I think this needs to be `lst[start:end+1]=lst[start:end+1][::-1]` but otherwise, the right solution. +1

Comment: @flakes Does this cost memory O(k)? k=length of sub string. or it swap one by one O(1)?

Comment: This is not an in-place reversal, it will use extra memory as slicing creates a new list.

Answer (score 2):

Partial reverse with no temporary list (replace `range` with `xrange` if you use Python 2):

```
def partial_reverse(list_, from_, to):
    for i in range(0, int((to - from_)/2)):
        (list_[from_+i], list_[to-i]) = (list_[to-i], list_[from_+i])

list_ = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
partial_reverse(list_, 3, 7)
print(list_)
```

Comment: That will give an error if you'll try the even length. For ex. partial_reverse(list_, 2, 7)==[1, 2, 8, 7, 5, 6, 4, 3]

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way to reverse a list in a partial or complete manner.

```
listVar = ['a','b','c','d']
def listReverse(list,start,end):
    while(start<end):
        temp = list[start]
        list[start] = list[end] #Swaping
        list[end]=temp
        start+=1
        end-=1
    print(list)


listReverse(listVar,1,3)
```

Output : - ['a', 'd', 'c', 'b']

Comment: Note there's no need for a temporary variable, just use a oneliner: `list[start], list[end] = list[end], list[start]`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you have a similar problem as mine, but i needed to reverse a list in place.

The only piece I was missing was **[:]**

```
exStr = "String"

def change(var):
  var[:] = var[::-1] # This line here

print(exStr) #"String"
change(exStr)
print(exStr) #"gnirtS"
```

Answer (score 0):

> ... I'm not sure is it's in place.

...

> ```
> lst[start:end]=sublist
> ```

Yes, it's in place. `lst` is never rebound, only its object mutated.

Comment: That said, ugh don't modify things in place :(

Answer (score 0):

Just use a slice:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
>>> lst[0:len(lst[3::-1])]=lst[3::-1]
>>> lst
[4, 3, 2, 1, 5]
```

Or, perhaps easier to understand:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
>>> sl=lst[3::-1]
>>> lst[0:len(sl)]=sl
>>> lst
[4, 3, 2, 1, 5]
```

Comment: That can't be what OP wants -- you're destroying indices. You want to do `start = 0` `end = 3` `lst[start:end] = lst[end-1::-1] if start==0 else lst[end-1:start-1:-1]`, which frankly should really be rewritten for readability into the function that OP posted to begin with!

Comment: Slicing with a negative stride is Tricky.

Comment: @adsmith Mismatch between lack of morning coffee and button trigger finger. Fixed.  As  Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams states, you have to think a little when slicing with a negative stride. Fingers help. Once you get the right relationship -- works great.

Answer (score 0):

`lst[::-1]` is the idiomatic way to reverse a list in Python, The following show how and that it was in-place:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> id(lst)
12229328
>>> lst[:] = lst[::-1]
>>> lst
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
>>> id(lst)
12229328
```

Answer (score 0):

Try some `crazy slicing`, see [Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation) and http://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

def sublist_reverse(start_rev, end_rev, lst):
    return lst[:end_rev-1:start_rev-1]+lst[:[end_rev]

print sublist_reverse(0,4,x)
```

[out]:

```
[8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have two ways for *in-place* reversal, the simple way is to loop through the list half-way, swapping the elements with the respective *mirror-elements*. By *mirror-element* I mean (first, last), (2nd, 2nd-last), (3rd, 3rd-last), etc.

```
def reverse_list(A):
    for i in range(len(A) // 2): # half-way
        A[i], A[len(A) - i - 1] = A[len(A) - i - 1], A[i] #swap
    return A
```

The other way is similar to the above but using recursion as opposed to a "loop":

```
def reverse_list(A):
    def rev(A, start, stop):
        A[start], A[stop] = A[stop], A[start] # swap
        if stop - start > 1: # until halfway
            rev(A, start + 1, stop - 1)
        return A

    return rev(A, 0, len(A) - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've conducted a tiny experiment and it seems that any assignment to list slice causes memory allocation:

```
import resource
resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_AS, (64 * 1024, 64 * 1024))

try:
    # Python 2
    zrange = xrange
    arr_size = 3 * 1024
except NameError:
    # Python 3
    zrange = range
    arr_size = 4 * 1024

arr = list(zrange(arr_size))

# We could allocate additional 100 integers, so there should be enough free memory
# to allocate a couple of variables for indexes in the statement below
#   additional_memory = list(zrange(100))

# MemoryError is raised here
arr[:] = zrange(arr_size)
```

So you have to use for loop to reverse a sublist in place.

PS: If you want to repeat this test, you should ensure that *setrlimit RLIMIT_AS* works fine on your platform. Also *arr_size* may vary for different python implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Two methods in-place and constant memory:

```
def reverse_swap(arr, start=None, end=None):
    """
    Swap two edge pointers until meeting in the center.
    """

    if start is None:
        start = 0
    if end is None:
        end = len(arr)

    i = start
    j = end - 1
    while i < j:
        arr[i], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[i]
        i += 1
        j -= 1

def reverse_slice(arr, start=None, end=None):
    """
    Use python slice assignment but use a generator on the right-hand-side
    instead of slice notation to prevent allocating another list.
    """

    if start is None:
        start = 0
    if end is None:
        end = len(arr)

    arr[start:end] = (arr[i] for i in range(end - 1, start - 1, -1))
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is probably to use slice assignment and [`reversed()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed):

```
lst[start:end] = reversed(lst[start:end])
```

You could also slice and reverse at the same time, however this generally requires either using negative indexes or specially handling the case when `start = 0`, i.e.:

```
lst[start:end] = lst[end-len(lst)-1:start-len(lst)-1:-1]
```

or

```
 lst[start:end] = lst[end-1::-1] if start == 0 else lst[end-1:start-1:-1]
```

OTOH, using slicing alone is *faster* than the `reversed()` solution.

Answer (score 0):

Much cleaner way to do this

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
i = 2
j = 7
while (i<j):
   a[i],a[j]=a[j],a[i]
   j -= 1
   i += 1
print(a)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

Suppose you have to reverse 2nd position to 4th position in place.

```
lst[2:5] = lst[2:5][::-1]
```

Output:

> [1,2,5,4,3,6,7,8]

Comment: Please explain your lines of code so other users can understand its functionality. Thanks!