# Why can't I use .reverse on a specific range in a list python?

Tags: python, list, reverse

I am writing a simple script, where I have a list of character and I want to loop over this list and reverse the ordered of 3 elements at a time. Ex. List: a,b,c,d,e,f ; Reversed list: c,b,a,f,e,d.

I tried to use
`print(list[0:2].reverse())`
however when I tried printing this it outputted NONE
My question is why does this happen?

FYI: I know there are other ways of doing this, I am just curious as to why this did not work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  ```reverse()``` doesn't return a new list.  It basically changes the original list.

Comment: `reverse` is side-effecting - that is, it modifies the list in place, rather than returning a new one.

Comment: sorry I wasnt very clear in the post. the line i used was `print(list[0:2].reverse())`, this prints NONE. I know that .reverse() does not create a new list. I am just wondering why it is not reverseing the order in the print

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reverse a sublist in a list in place?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22257249/how-do-i-reverse-a-sublist-in-a-list-in-place)

Comment: unfortunately no. I am trying to understand why this does not work, not how do I do the reversal. I already achieved this. My question is more of a theoretical question rather than a practical one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do a slicing operation e.g `list[0:2]`, you essentially create a new list

Since reverse operates on the object you give it, but doesn't return anything, if you were to do `print(list.reverse())` it would still print `None` because reverse doesn't return anything, but modify the object you use it on.

Now, since slicing creates a new list, when you do `list[0:2].reverse()` , you are modifying the list created by the slicing, which is also immediately lost since you don't assign it to any variable (and you can't since reverse doesn't return a value). Essentially, you are creating a list with the slicing, modying it, and then losing it forever

Additionally, you can assign the slicing to a variable and then use reverse on it, but it wouldn't be useful in your case

```
listed= ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
sliced = listed[0:2]
sliced.reverse()
print(sliced) prints ['b', 'a']
```

Hope this is clear

(Last advice, don't call your list "`list`", it shadows the built-in name)

Comment: I tried assigning it to a variable and printing that variable it still printed NONE. `ak=a[0:2].reverse()` `print(ak)` the ourput is still NONE PS: yes I am aware of not naming the list as 'list', in practice i dont do this, however for the sake of this question i just named it list here.

Comment: You did exactly what I warned in my post,  assign the slice to a variable before, and then use reverse on that variable (no assignation), reverse modify the CURRENT OBJECT you are using it on, as explained on my answer, but doesn't return anything, var = smt.reverse() will always be None, but smt will be modified

Comment: Ohh my bad, this makes sense now. So even if I assign it like this var=listy[0:2].reverse() it will still be NONE as the return of the reverse is NONE. Thank you so much I finally get it now!

Comment: yes exactly! and since listy[0:2] creates a new list but you're never stocking it, using reverse on it is useless. Reverse modifies listy[0:2] which is a new list, but you never stocked this list beforhand, so it's lost, ence why you need to first store listy[0:2] in a var ( var = listy[0:2] ) and then use reverse on var ( var.reverse()) to modify var (note that I don't do var = var.reverse() because it would make var = None)

Answer (score 3):

```
lst[0:2].reverse()
```

does not do much to the original list `lst`, because the slice operation `lst[0:2]` returns a new independent list object which is then reversed in-place by reverse. The original `lst` is unimpressed by this. You have to feed the reversed slice back with slice assignment to mutate the original. E.g.:

```
lst[0:2] = lst[0:2][::-1]
```

You could also use `list.reverse`'s brother `reversed` , which does return an object (an reverse order iterator):

```
lst[0:2] = reversed(lst[0:2])
```

Comment: I understand that it does not affect the original list, my question is when i use print(list[0:2].reverse()) the output is NONE, so this means that .reverse does not work on subsets of the list. My question is why this is the case?

Comment: it prints `None`because `list.reverse()` returns `None` (since the list is modified in-place). if you want to print the list, you'll either need to use `reversed`(which does return something, as stated in the answer, i.e. `print(*reversed(lst))`), or do the reversing and printing that in separate statements (i.e. `lst.reverse(); print(lst)`).